# How to convert MySQL field types?

Tags: mysql, fieldtype

I have already come across the convert function. As I understand it, the basic syntax is:

```
select convert(columnName, targetFieldType) as newColumnName from table;
```

Running this command doesn't give me any errors, but when I check the data types they are unchanged. Even when I use commit; the data remains unchanged. In particular, I'm trying to convert data with long type to varchar. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The given `SELECT` query will *return* the value in the new type, but it doesn't change the field type of the table in your database.

If you want to permanently change the table on disk, use:

```
ALTER TABLE table CHANGE columnName newColumnName targetFieldType NOT NULL;
```

Note that for large tables, this can take a while, because MySQL rewrites the entire table.

Note: remove the `NOT NULL` qualifier if you also want to allow NULL values in this column.

For more information, see [ALTER TABLE Syntax in MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/alter-table.html).

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can convert anything to character type easily by using CONCAT:

```
select concat(columnName,'') as newColumnName from table;
```

The actual syntax you want for CONVERT is as follows:

```
select convert(columnName, char) as newColumnName from table;
```

There is no varchar type available to CONVERT or CAST, but casting to char without giving the field length should be the result you want.