# the select convert function not working ! Return the syntax error?

Tags: mysql, sql, dbeaver

I am using DBeaver.  Here is my piece of code:

```
select convert(varchar(10), updated_at, 101)
from rewards.mission_actions
limit 30
```

This is the error:

> [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near ","

Because the data is too specific to extend of hour and minute so I want to change it. Not extract details out of it.

Please help or at least give me another solution.

Comment: [`Convert()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) function takes only two arguments. Why do you have third argument ? What are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert MySQL field types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1742624/how-to-convert-mysql-field-types)

Comment: What is your actual database?  Are you using MySQL, DB-Beaver, something else?

Comment: You're using the convert function syntax from SQL Server which accepts upto three arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CONVERT` function is for SQL Server, not MySQL.  The closest analog in MySQL would be `DATE_FORMAT`:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, '%m/%d/%Y')
FROM rewards.missions_actions
-- ORDER BY <something>
LIMIT 30
```